# Joomla location redirect

Tags: php, joomla, location, ip-address, ip-geolocation

I'm looking for an extension (or script) by which I can redirect the user who enters the website to his own language.

I use the Joomla CMS and in this CMS i've built 4 different languages. Is there an extension available who identifies the IP and based on that redirects it to the English or French version of the website?

Basically, all the urls are like this http://www.example.com/en/ and http://www.example.com/fr/

I was looking around, but I'm not familiar with this field and I think I'm looking at the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isn't an extension that I know of that can redirect the user based on their IP address for a specific language, however what you can do is enable the plugin **System - Language Filter**. Once it also gives you the option **Language Selection for new Visitors** either depending on their browser language or their site settings.

Do bare in mind that this plugin should only be enabled when the **Language Switcher** module is published.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I have some directions to look into :) I never heard of this module before, and I also stumbled accross this website:

http://docs.joomla.org/Language_Switcher_Tutorial

Might be usefull for others as well!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a extension that might be of help to anyone landing on this post namely **User GeoIP Location Menu Item Redirect**, can be found by visiting this link https://jdev.l-it.co.za/products/user-geoip-location-menu-item-redirect.

This extension basically can redirect users based on the users IP address country code. When a user lands on a menu, the user will be redirected to a different menu item based on his IP country code.